# PHP Website Framework Question - Reviewing Structure

Tags: php, frameworks

I've been designing a php website for my school on and off for about a year now - this is really just a way for me to learn php and designing. However, lately I've been feeling like the whole system is broken. Is there a place where I could host the "framework" and site for people to review it and point out problems and areas to fix? Naturally I would remove passwords and other sensitive data. Is this practical / safe? Where would I put all the files?

Keiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a place where I could host
>   the "framework" and site for people to
>   review it and point out problems and
>   areas to fix?

If you want to run it with **ftp** support, **mysql**, **SVN** and more and something that if free, check out:

- [Kodingen](http://kodingen.com/)

Comment: You sir win the awesomeness badge! This will help me out SO much!